# Добавление OneToOne связей в админку

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Есть две модели связанный друг с другом через OneToOne.

```
class Profile(models.model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name = 'profile', null=True)

class User(AbstractUser):
    #fields
```

Каждая модель размещается в смоем приложении(app) и имеет свой файл admin.py.

Для Profile admin.py выглядит так

```
    class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        #prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("profile.last_name",)}
        list_display = ('id', 'get_trainer_name', 'add_date', 'city', 'is_active', 'pause')
        inlines = [PortfolioImageInline,
                   OrderInline,
                   ]
        list_display_links = ['id', 'get_trainer_name']
        save_on_top = True
        list_filter = ['is_active']

        def get_trainer_name(self, obj):
            return obj.user.get_full_name()

admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

Каким образом можно вывести поля модели User в админке на странице Profile и добавить prepopulated_fields (закоменченная строка в коде)? Способ с Inlines работает только для ForeignKey. Вывод полей Profile в User работает без проблем, но надо наоборот. Если это вообще возможно в Django.

Comment: Отношения один-к-одному нормально отображаются в формах через inline_model

Comment: @МистерФикс Только на стороне без связи OneToOne, обратно нет. Может я ошибаюсь, тогда скажите где посмотреть пример.